# Solving a quadratic expression

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

I have an equation of the form: $$x'Ax - B$$ where $A$ is a positive definite matrix. I want to solve this equation for $x$. Could anyone provide me with some suggestions on how to solve this kind of quadratic expression?

Comment: what is $B?$ What are the restrictions on $x,$ if any

Comment: $B$ is just a 1x1 scalar; $x$ is 4x1 vector and $A$ is 4x4 positive definite matrix.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, making up an ellipsoid when B > 0. When B= 0, it is just the origin. When B < 0, empty set. The set of solutions becomes finite when $B$ is a positive integer and $2A$ has all integer entries.

Comment: I don´t see an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a guess about what you might mean by the word solve. First, find a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)
$$ C^T C = A.  $$
Find
$$ W = C^{-1}. $$
Take any real column vector  $y$ such that
$$ |y|^2 = y \cdot y = B.  $$
Then 
$$ x = W y  $$
gives
$$ x^T A x = B. $$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there some "name" for this kind of algorithm that you have used(from Step-2 to Step-5)?Also, since $B$ is a scalar, should I take $y = sqrt(B)$?

Comment: $y$ is a vector. You may take $y_1 = \sqrt B$ and $y_2 = y_3 = y_4 = 0$ if you like. Or you may take $y_2 = \sqrt B$ and $y_1 = y_3 = y_4 = 0.$ No name.